# Blender Automatic Weights: Is it grabbing more mesh than it should?

Tags: rigging

When I use automatic weights when parenting a model and armature, it works but there's an issue where it seems to grab more "mesh" around it. For example, when I rotate the left leg to test if it's been rigged properly, the leg moves but so does part of the right boot(it stretches and follows the movement of that leg)

Another example is the braids I've rigged, except instead of following another limb/the wrong bone, they stay in place when I move the character's midsection(plus the eyes also stay in the same place but I'm not going to worry about that now)

Does anyone else experience this issue with automatic rigging? If I were to change the model's default pose from the classic "T" pose to one that looks like a jumping jack and try it, would that help or not?

Here's a few screenshots of the issues I'm talking about but I will not be uploading the model itself(*past experiences with thieves*)
[image: Grace Model is Property of CraftyMaelyss]

I've rigged a very basic "Test Model" for my game I'm working on and it's basically a blank mannequin in appearance that never gave me this issue. If it's because of the details, is there a way to avoid these random bits from moving with the wrong limb or detaching from the model?

I'm still fairly new to blender but I've learned enough of the basics to get me this far, however any help would be appreciated(*again I'm not uploading the model file because of thieves*)

Usually I join the clothes to the model but in this case I haven't because I want to update the outfit later on and rather then build from scratch, it'd be easier to switch them out.

I used the same method of parenting the armature and body for the dress, boots and hair.

Also if anyone knows how to make the eyes, teeth and tongue follow the head(WITHOUT joining these models to the main body) I would greatly appreciate it since whenever I try, the mouth becomes huge and appears in the centre of the grid.

Comment: You should add some pictures or upload your file. But yes, sometimes automatic weights may fails on some parts, or that can be a symmetry problem on your mesh... really depending on the situation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, automatic weights don't always give the desired deformations.  You'll likely have to weight paint things manually to get the exact look you're going for.  I'd set my weight paint mode to 'Add', and set the strength to 1.0, and weight paint the leg bones to 1 -- then normalize everything when you're done.

If you'd like the eyes, teeth and tongue to remain separate mesh objects, you can try putting an armature modifier on those mesh objects too, and weight paint those on the same way you would the rest of your model.